# Call SSIS package from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, teradata

How can we call an SSIS package from a stored procedure and pass it a parameter?

Comment: which version of SQL Server?

Comment: how is teradata related here?

Comment: if you are using sql server 2012 and have an [ssis catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh479588.aspx) defined, you can [call the package stored in the catalog from the sql procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can enable xp_cmdshell extended stored procedure, and using it you can execute DTEXEC utility to execute your SSIS package. The disadvantage of using this approach is that enablement of xp_cmdshell poses security threats (operating system level access) and hence by default it's disabled. However using this approach provides finer level control of passing SSIS package variables' at runtime values easily.

check out the following article for details.http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/executing-a-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server.html

OR this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27156/How-to-Call-SSIS-Package-from-the-Stored-Procedure

Comment: I don't have access of xp_cmdshell.Any other method by which i can call and also i want to pass the parameter in stored procedure so that the in ssis package it change the variable according to the need.??

Comment: are you meaning that you don't have permissions to enable xp_cmdshell?

Comment: yes,i don't have .But my problem is that i parameterized  the "id" in where clause.I want to pass the value in stored procedure of sql server and it should change the id in ssis and fetch the result for that ?

Comment: You could try the first approach mentioned in the first link but the disadvantage of using that approach is you don't have an easy way of  passing some values (SSIS package variables) at run time.

Comment: i deployed and able to run.But problem is passing the variables.variables. Plz help me in that...